# how put date range from week picker for two text input?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I'm new in javascript.
I have week-picker from this link [week-picker](https://github.com/morshedalam/week-picker), but i dont know how i can put that date range for two text input??
start date - end date.
ex. `<input type="text" name='start_date' id="start_date"/> TO  <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date"/>`

Comment: Why did you tag this with php?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this:

```
<input type="text" name='start_date' id="start_date" data-weekpicker="weekpicker" />
<input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" data-weekpicker="weekpicker" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to just split the value from the week-picker input:

```
var range = document.getElementById("weekPickerInput").value;
var dates = range.split("-"); //Based on what divider you configured for the week picker

document.getElementById("startDateInput").value = dates[0];
document.getElementById("endDateInput").value = dates[1];
```

Comment: i'm really sorry, i dont understand yet,
the original source html like this :

<input type="text" readonly="" id="week_range"/>
<span class="add-on" data-weekpicker="weekpicker" data-target="#week_range">
<i class="icon-th"></i>
</span>.

so, ex date. (25/11/13-01/12/13) in one text input, how to separate it to two text input

please help